# Sequelize QueryGenerator and scope

Tags: sequelize.js

```js
const model = MyModel.scope(scopes);
const { queryGenerator } = model;
const queryOptions = {
  scopes,
  attributes,
  include,
  where,
  order,
  offset,
  limit,
};
model._validateIncludedElements.bind(model)(queryOptions);

const cte = queryGenerator.selectQuery(
  model.getTableName(),
  queryOptions,
  model
)
  .slice(0, -1);
```

I have two issue with the query generator

1. The scope is ignored (Including default scope), How can I apply scopes in the query generator?
2. The attributes are in camel case instead of snack case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading source code on the sequelize I found the solution, `Utils.mapFinderOptions` and `model._injectScope`

```js
const model = MyModel.scope(scopes);
const { queryGenerator } = model;
const queryOptions = {
  scopes,
  attributes,
  include,
  where,
  order,
  offset,
  limit,
};
model._injectScope(queryOptions);
model._validateIncludedElements.bind(model)(queryOptions);

Utils.mapFinderOptions(queryOptions, model);

const cte = queryGenerator.selectQuery(
  model.getTableName(),
  queryOptions,
  model
)
  .slice(0, -1);
```